# Skip calling rest controller class using handler intercptor

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, interceptor, spring-restcontroller

I have write a small rest api using spring boot.

url - http://localhost:8080/REST/api/testservice

### Test Controller class

```
@RestController
@Scope("request")
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class TestRestController {
    private final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    @Autowired
    Common common;

    @Autowired
    CommonVarList commonVarList;


    @CrossOrigin
    @RequestMapping(value = "/testservice", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseBean> getCheckUser() {
        return new ResponseEntity<ResponseBean>(new ResponseBean(Boolean.parseBoolean(commonVarList.BOOLEAN_DEFAULT_TRUE),common.getLocaleMessage(MessageVarList.IB_SERVICE_RUNNING)), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

I have write a interceptor class too.

### Intercetor class

```
public class TestRestInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(IbRestInterceptor.class);

    @Autowired
    Common common;

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Object o) throws Exception {
        //check request time out here
        boolean isRequestTimeOut = common.checkUserTimeOut();
        if(isRequestTimeOut){
            httpServletResponse.sendRedirect(httpServletRequest.getContextPath()+"/api/request/timeout");
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Object o, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        //TODO
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Object o, Exception e) throws Exception {}
}
```

### TimeOut Rest Controller class

```
@RestController
@Scope("request")
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/request")
public class ResponseRestController {

    @Autowired
    RequestHandlerService requestHandlerService;

    @CrossOrigin
    @RequestMapping(value = "/timeout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseBean> postUserTimeOut(){
        ResponseBean responseBean=requestHandlerService.handleRequestTimeOut();
        return new ResponseEntity<ResponseBean>(responseBean,HttpStatus.REQUEST_TIMEOUT);
    }
}
```

I have use **httpServletResponse.sendRedirect** to skip calling **/api/testservice** rest controller class when user request is timeout.

But it call the **/api/testservice**  rest controller class and then call the **/api/request/timeout** rest controller class.

I want to just skip calling **/api/testservice** rest controller class when user request timeout.

Is any one can describehow to fix this issue. it will be great helpful. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docs says

> DispatcherServlet processes a handler in an execution chain,
>   consisting of any number of interceptors, with the handler itself at
>   the end. With this method, each interceptor can decide to abort the
>   execution chain, typically sending a HTTP error or writing a custom
>   response.

And description o `preHandle` method

> Returns:
>       true if the execution chain should proceed with the next interceptor or the handler itself. Else, DispatcherServlet assumes
>   that this interceptor has already dealt with the response itself.

So if you throw an exception or write response in interceptor and return false, call wont get to the actual handler (controler).

Comment: Thank u very much.your answer help me to understand internal work flow.But how can i stop request to get actual handler.I try below code.It doesn't work.                    
                                  
RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher=httpServletRequest.getRequestDispatcher("/api/request/timeout");
requestDispatcher.forward(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);

Comment: `return false` in your prehandle.

Comment: cant do return false.I have to return response body for api caller with description request time out.

Comment: @Shalika you write resonse directly to the stream, and then return false to skip futher processing.